# What does this awk sentence mean?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk

I have the following sentence in awk

```
$ gawk '$2 == "-"  { print $1 }' file
```

I was wondering what thing this instruction exactly did because I can't parse exactly the words I need.

Edit: How can I do in order to skip the lines before the following astersiks?
Let's say I have the following lines:

```
text
text
text                


            * * * * * * *

line1 - 
line2 -
```

And then I want to filter just

```
line1
line2
```

with the sentence I posted above...

```
$ gawk '$2 == "-"  { print $1 }' file
```

Thanks for your time and response!

Comment: That script really couldn't be any clearer or more basic so if you don't understand what that does, you definitely should not be trying to write anything in awk yourself yet. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins, read the first chapter or 2 and work through a couple of examples and you will have no problem understanding that script.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton I have just downloaded the book. I just wanted to know this because I had to figure it out as a hurry for school. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to the original question:**

If the second column in a line from the file matches the string "-" then it prints out the first column of the line, columns are by default separated by spaces.

This would match and print out `one`:

```
one - two three
```

This would not:

```
one two three four
```

**Answer to the revised question:**

This code should do what you need **after** the match of the given string:

```
awk '/\* \* \* \* \* \* \*/{i++}i && $2 == "-" { print $1 }' data2.txt
```

Testing on [this data](http://pastebin.com/MzdJ2BQv) gives the following output:

```
2two
2two
```

Comment: Thanks @Olafur Osvaldsson. I will try it and post what happened.

Comment: I ran the line @Olafur Osvaldsson although I did not get any exit in the prompt. It just appears as a valid command but does not show anything... Any idea why? thanks in advance!

Comment: Not without seeing the data you are testing it with, it worked with the dummy data I made up from the information in your question.

Comment: Oh I see. I could get it work, although it was my fault because what I need to parse is just the information that matches the regular expression after the asterisks not before... What should I change to make that work? Thanks for your time again @Olafur Osvaldsson

Comment: It was actually my fault for using the same data before and after the asterisks, lazy copying.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses @Olafur Osvaldsson. Although, with the new sentence you edited, I cannot get an exit in the prompt. I mean no lines are printed in the prompt

Comment: That is a direct copy of what I ran on my console, what is the output when you run the command on the new test data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35959/discussion-between-mike-perez-and-olafur-osvaldsson)

Answer (score 3):

This will find all lines on which the second column (Separated by spaces) is a -, and will then print the first column.

The first part ($2 == "-") checks for the second column being a -, and then if that is the case, runs the attached {} block, which prints the first column ($0 being the whole line, and $1, $2, etc being the first, second, ... columns.)

Spaces are the separator here simply because they are the default separator in awk.

Edit: To do what you want to do now, try the following (Not the most elegant, but it should work.)

```
gawk 'BEGIN { p = 0 } { if (p != 0 && $2 == "-") { print $1 } else { p = ($0 == "* * * * * * *")? 1 : 0 } }'
```

Spread over more lines for clarity on what's happening:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { p = 0 }
            { if (p != 0 && $2 == "-")
                 { print $1 }
              else
                 { p = ($0 == "* * * * * * *")? 1 : 0 }
            }'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @qaphla. I am gonna try something with my code then

Comment: If you're trying to do something specific, you could probably ask directly about that and get help here just fine, too.

Comment: Thanks @qaphla. I will try it and will tell you what goes on.

Comment: I have run the script and it does not show anything. Not even in console... I ran the following: awk -f filter.awk(this contains the lines of the script you just posted above) file.txt Any idea why?

Comment: The issue is that the separating line appears not to actually be "* * * * * * *", but that string with a bunch of spaces before it. Since I can't tell exactly what that separating line is, perhaps either replace that part of the code with the actual separating line, or use some utility like sed to parse the file first and replace that separating line with something that's easier to detect.